# why same category base and single post base don't work?

Tags: wp-query, categories, permalinks

I have checked a similar question on the site but there was no satisfactory answer? Here is what I would like to accomplish.

When I set the permalink structure to '/blog/%postname%/' this gives me the result I want.

mydomain.com/blog/my-post

However, when I also add category base 'blog' it creates an error.

This is what I would want to get:

'mydomain.com/blog/my-category'

I know this has got something to do with wp_query and how wordpress resolves permalinks but, can someone explain why it fails? I mean the logic?

I have seen some sort of tricks to overcome this but I want to stay within the natural functionality of wordpress and follow the best practices.

Any explanation is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you set WordPress up with:

### The set-up

**Custom Permalink Structure:** /blog/%postname%/
**Category base:** blog

### Generated rewrite rules

WordPress generates these rewrite rules:

1. blog/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ => index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
2. blog/(.+?)/?$ => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]

### Rewrite rule position in the rewrite_rules_array

Your **post** rewrite rule (**#1**) is positioned earlier (therefore higher priority) than the **category** rewrite rule (**#2**) in your [rewrite_rules_array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rewrite_rules_array/). This allows your post URLs to work and causes your category URLs to fail.

Where the rewrite rule is positioned in the **rewrite_rules_array** matters.

### Similar regular expression pattern

The regular expression in your **post** rewrite rule (**#1**) matches **both** `mydomain.com/blog/my-post` and `mydomain.com/blog/my-category`. So, when you attempt to visit `https://example.com/blog/<category_name>`, WordPress does this:

Using this:

```
blog/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ => index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

converts this:

```
https://example.com/blog/some-category
```

into this:

```
index.php?name=some-category&page=
```

(**page** is automatically added by WordPress for front-page pagination).

Since *name* is in the query string, WordPress searches for a **post** with **post_name** (slug) of *some-category* and tries to display it using a single post template (e.g. single.html). This likely results in a 404 (not found) page. The desired outcome is to have WordPress recognize *some-category* as a **category_name** and display the results using a category archive template (e.g. category.html).

### Solution

Using a [WP_Rewrite->front](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/#properties) (*blog*) and a matching Category base (*blog*) violates conventional WordPress configuration. WordPress uses a different front for different items: *category* for category, *tag* for tag. Notice that WordPress does not use the front *category* for both category and tag. Also, keep in mind the list of [WordPress Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms).

If you must adhere to this non-conventional set-up, you should be able to do it using the [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action hook. The idea is to test `is_404()` to see if the situation presented under **Similar regular expression pattern** has occurred. If it did, run a new WP_Query with arguments that look for results using the **category_name** parameter. The remainder of your solution is found in the answer to this question in WordPress Stack Exchange: [Load a specific post if user tries to access 404 page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/415243). Be careful to set the appropriate conditional tag property (**is_category**) to *true*.